# Matlab Data Acquisition, PCI card incorrectly detected as a PXI Chassis card

Tags: matlab, data-acquisition, nidaqmx, daq-mx

In Matlab 2014b,2014a,2013b,2013a (not using simulink)

Windows7 64-bit session based data acquisition toolbox

Using NI-DAQmx 14.1 and NI-DAQmx 14.0

I have a PCI card that is being incorrectly detected as being present in a PXI chassis. This causes operations such as the following to fail as they are incorrectly referencing the nonexistent PXI chassis card instead of my actually installed PCI card.

obj.startBackground(), obj.startForeground(), 
Both generate errors. For example:

```
> close all force; daq.reset;
> devID = 'Dev1';
> niIn = daq.createSession('ni');
> niIn.IsContinuous = true;
> aI = niIn.addAnalogInputChannel(devID,[0],'Voltage');
> dI = niIn.addDigitalChannel(devID,{'Port0/Line0'},'InputOnly');
> niIn.startBackground();
> NI Error -89120:
> Source terminal to be routed could not be found on the device.
>
> Make sure the terminal name is valid for the specified device.
> Refer to Measurement & Automation Explorer for valid terminal
> names.
> Property: DAQmx_RefClk_Src
> Source Device: Dev1
> Source Terminal: PXI_CLK10
>
> Task Name: _unnamedTask<1D1>
>
> Status Code: -89120
Looking at the output of daq.getDevices points to a problem with the incorrect recognition:

> daq.getDevices()
>
> ni: National Instruments PCI-6251 (Device ID: 'Dev1')
>    Analog input subsystem supports:
>       7 ranges supported
>       Rates from 0.1 to 1000000.0 scans/sec
>       16 channels ('ai0' - 'ai15')
>       'Voltage' measurement type
>
>    Analog output subsystem supports:
>       -5.0 to +5.0 Volts,-10 to +10 Volts ranges
>       Rates from 0.1 to 2857142.9 scans/sec
>       2 channels ('ao0','ao1')
>       'Voltage' measurement type
>
>    Digital subsystem supports:
>       Rates from 0.1 to 10000000.0 scans/sec
>       24 channels ('port0/line0' - 'port2/line7')
>       'InputOnly','OutputOnly','Bidirectional' measurement types
>
>    Counter input subsystem supports:
>       Rates from 0.1 to 80000000.0 scans/sec
>       2 channels ('ctr0','ctr1')
>       'EdgeCount','PulseWidth','Frequency','Position' measurement
> types
>
>    Counter output subsystem supports:
>       Rates from 0.1 to 80000000.0 scans/sec
>       2 channels ('ctr0','ctr1')
>       'PulseGeneration' measurement type
>
> This module is in slot 4294967295 of the PXI Chassis 4294967295.
>
> Properties, Methods, Events
```

**This module is in slot 4294967295 of the PXI Chassis 4294967295.**

Could somebody please advise a solution? [Here is the output of daqsupport](https://gist.github.com/stephenholtz/837a52bb0dbdd8e4accf)  as the text file it generates as well (although it is mostly redundant with above information).

Note that this occurs with a fresh install of 64-bit windows7.

Answer (score 0):

Rolling back my drivers to NI-DAQmx 9.8 solves this problem for all tested versions of Matlab (2013a-2014b).